# Flip pixels over an imaginary horizontal line

Tags: java

I need to flip an image over an imaginary horizontal line and can't figure out how to do it.

This is the code I have currently, eclipse is telling me that the value of hold is not used but I don't see how it's not. All help is appreciated.

```
public static void flipH(Picture p){

    int height= p.getHeight();
    int width= p.getWidth();

    Pixel empty= new Pixel(v, 0, 0);
    Pixel hold= new Pixel(v, 0, 0);

    for(int i=0; i< height; i++) {
        for(int j=0, r=width-1; j<width/2 && r>width/2; j++, r--) {
            empty= p.getPixel(i, j);
            hold = p.getPixel(i, r);
            hold= empty;                
        }
    }               
}
```

Comment: Eclipse is telling you that the **VALUE** of `hold` is not used because it is not used. You are just assigning something to `hold`, but not **using** its **VALUE**.

Comment: Do you know how I could use hold to set the pixels on the right side of the image to the left? @MasterYushi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

empty and hold are only references, aka pointers, arrows that points to the real object.
Assigning empty and hold to point to some pixel will never change the pixel.
To swap two pixels you need something like...

```
    int a = p.getColorOfPixel(x, y1);
    int b = p.getColorOfPixel(x, y2);
    p.setColorOfPixel(x, y1, b);
    p.setColorOfPixel(x, y2, a);
```